# Formatting the address field in a biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

How can I format (e.g., italic) the field `address` for an @report in a biblatex bibliography?

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{institution+location+date}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

or

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{address}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

do not work.
**Update:**
and neither

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{location}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

It works for e.g. `title` instead of `location` though, so it must be something specific to `location`.

NB: I know I can include formatting of fields in the .bib file, but I very much prefer a solution along the lines of `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Thanks for any hint!

**Update2**: MWEB

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  location = {My location}
}
\end{filecontents}    
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{location}{\mkbibemph{#1}}    
\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}    
\printbibliography    
\end{document}
```

Result: "My location" is not formatted in italic font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since the answer will heavily depend on the style you use, you can increase your chance of getting a good answer by including an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). In this case I ventured a guess, but I can't be sure if it really solves your problem without testing. And often a guess along those lines is near-impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`address` is a legacy name kept for backwards compatibility. Internally `address` is remapped to the `location` field. Furthermore, `location` is a list, so you need

```
\DeclareListFormat[report]{location}{%
  \mkbibemph{%
    \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
    #1\isdot
    \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried `location` as well, it didn't work. I edited my question.

Comment: I included the MWE(B) in my question.

Comment: Great thanks! I learned something. In my case `\DeclareListFormat[report]{location}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` was enough, but please use moewe's suggestion which is certainly more general.

Comment: @monade Note that your redefinition will cripple the ability to deal with more than one location as in `location = {Oxford and Cambridge}` or `location = {Oxford and Cambridge and Warwick}`